# How do i get multiple single objects in a json converted into a C# object list?

Tags: c#, json, api

Im trying to make a program using the League of legends API. The API doesnt return a array of objects. It has different objects for each champions. My question is, how can i get these objects into a c# list without having to make a object for each champion in C#?
https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion?api_key=362039df-6ce4-4e2f-ac3c-27d246d03f45
(This is the json list im getting)
I have the following code to convert the objects, but obviously it cannot fill the list.

```
var webclient = new WebClient();
var strJson = webclient.DownloadString("https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion?api_key=362039df-6ce4-4e2f-ac3c-27d246d03f45");
var List<ChampionJson> = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectList<<ChampionJson>>(strJson);
```

This is the champion class:

```
public class ChampionJson
{
    public Champion champion { get; set; }
}

public class Champion
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

I know its probably completely wrong what im doing but im pretty new to Json. I have been trying to get it to work the past two days but i cannot find anything on the internet. 
Pls help, 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include a sample of the JSON you're trying to deserialize in your question, and please elaborate on why your code isn't working - "it cannot fill the list" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Obviously you need to create same number of objects as the values in `json` response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object basically needs to reflect the model the JSON is providing. You are quite close; I would change the ChampionJson object definition to:

```
public class ChampionJson { public Dictionary<string, Champion> data { get; set; } }
```

and then use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChampionJson>(strJson)
```

instead of

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectList<<ChampionJson>>(strJson)
```

Comment: Whenever I need to write something off hand and want to verify I use https://dotnetfiddle.net/. You can even include packages via nuget. Just a tip.

Comment: @Default I had no idea that even existed. I am truly grateful! Thank you! - tested my answer and it works :)

Comment: I did what u explained and it gives the var champion no data, it just has null values

Comment: Did you rename the Dictionary<string,Champion> property in ChampionJson to 'data', as I wrote? If yes, can you edit your question and paste the code that you've changed?

Comment: Here's a dotnetfiddle, with your code working (thanks to @Default) https://dotnetfiddle.net/nS9qXh

Comment: Wow its working now, a big thanks for taking the time out of your day to help me:) I pasted your code, and now its indeed working, mustve overlooked something i guess

Comment: How would i put these items in a listbox? Sorry, im still learning how to program :/

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. With regards to your listbox, I suggest you open a new question and detailing what platform you're coding for (Web/Windows) and post what you've tried so far :)